MediaTailor multilingual Ad configuration
I have a URL for content that directs to an HLS stream, and another URL for an ad decision server which has VAST XML having mediaFile tag points to a different HLS stream. However, when I create a mediaTailor configuration and play the URL, the language chosen on the HLS player during the content playback is not preserved language during the Ad playback. Could you explain why this is happening? Is there a requirement for additional configuration?
P.S: I have already read about the player parameters configuration - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/variables-player.html. In my case, the scenario is completely SSAI and should work on any player.

I have explored further here. I could see the #EXT-X-CUE-OUT:0, #EXT-X-CUE-IN tags properly on both audio and video master playlist. My Ad decision server points to another HLS segment and that has the proper audio and video segments. But when mediaTailor stitches, it manipulates and add only ts segments to both.

I could see two playlists here one for videos and other for audios - but MediaTailor stiches only ts segments to both, whereas I'm expecting it to ts for video and aac for audio
